# discord.js user does not contain all properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to my update my discord bot to discord.js v12.
`dc` is a logged in discord bot client

```
dc.users.fetch(id, false).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
User {
  id: 'myId',
  username: 'myUsername',
  bot: false,
  discriminator: 'someNumber',
  avatar: 'stuff',
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessageChannelID: null
}
```

Where are all the properties a user object should normally contain?
`user.dmChannel` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties (`user.tag`, `user.guild`, etc.) are **getters**. It means that they are calculated using other variables in the object. For example, `tag` is not a property of the `user` class, it's just a function that returns a string:

```js
get tag () {
    return `${this.username}#${this.discriminator}`;
}
```

It is better, because if the username changes, the tag will automatically be updated. You can't see all the getters of the user using `console.log(user);`, you should use [the documentation](https://discord.js.org) instead.

Comment: thanks, I also ran this before the client was ready. No wonder nothing worked